# How to resolve Error 10045 when sending data on port 80 using python 2.7

Tags: python, http, server, port80

The program is using python 2.7 and I'm using google as my browser.

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 80))
server_socket.listen(10)
client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print 'New client'
req = client_socket.recv(1024)
data = '0123'
client_socket.send(data, len(data))
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

When I run the program and enter to the browser http://127.0.0.1:80 it raises the following error:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../HttpServer.py", line 7, in 
    client_socket.send(data, len(data))
socket.error: [Errno 10045] The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced**

I looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) for the error code 10045 but I did not fully understand what I should do.

The error occurs only when len(data) is larger than 5 or if I don't receive data from the client. If len(data) is 1-4 the data is sent as expected, but if it's exactly 5 then no error rises but the fifth char doesn't get sent.
The error has never occurred to me on any other ports.
Any ideas how to resolve this issue and why does it happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Trust me, you are not using Google as your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don´t enter bytes size

```
client_socket.send(data, len(data))  # Errno 10045

client_socket.send(data)  # Works
```

Comment: The reason could be that because python reads a new line as \n and windows as \r\n the byte length was wrong